# Sum for Distinct values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, distinct

I have three tables, the structure is listed as following.

This table (called `contest_submissions`) stores the relationship of submissions and contests.

```
ContestID | SubmissionID

1           1000
1           1001
1           1002
1           1003
```

The second table (called `submissions`) stores the detail information of a submission:

```
SubmissionID | ProblemID | User | Score | Time

1000           1000        A      100     1000
1001           1000        A      40      1250
1002           1001        A      50      1500
1003           1001        B      20      1750
```

Another table (called `contest_contestants`) is consisted of:

```
ContestID | User

1           A
1           B
```

I wrote the following SQL:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUM(score)
    FROM  contest_submissions cs
    NATURAL JOIN submissions
    WHERE user = cc.user
    AND SubmissionID = cs.SubmissionID
) AS TotalScore, (
    SELECT SUM(Time)
    FROM contest_submissions cs
    NATURAL JOIN submissions
    WHERE user = cc.user
    AND SubmissionID = cs.SubmissionID
) AS TotalTime
FROM contest_contestants cc
WHERE contestID = 1
```

I got following result (Suppose `ContestID = 1`):

```
contestID | User | Total Score | Total Time
1           A      190           3750
1           B      20            1750
```

where `190 = 100 + 40 + 50`.

However, I want to get following result:

```
contestID | User | Total Score | Total Time
1           A      150           2500
1           B      20            1750
```

where `150 = MAX(100, 40) + 50`, because `100` and `40` come from the same problem (with the same `ProblemID`).

What should I do?

BTW, I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try something like that:

```
select User, sum(MaxScore)
from
(
select User, ProblemID, max(Score) as MaxScore
from submissions
group by User, ProblemId
) as t
group by User
```

Comment: HI, there. I've updated my question. What should I do if I need more information from the query?

Comment: I suppose you need to adjust query

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I think there is a way to do this with only one `group by`:

```
select s.user, sum(s.score)
from submissions s
where s.submissionId = (select s2.submissionId
                        from submissions s2
                        where s2.user = s.user and s2.ProblemId = s.ProblemId
                        order by s2.score desc
                        limit 1
                       )
group by s.user;
```

I offer this as a solution because with an index on `submissions(user, ProblemId, score, submissionId)` it should have somewhat better performance than the solutions with two aggregations.

Comment: You need a second condition in your subquery: `and s2.ProblemID = s.ProblemID`.

Comment: HI, there. I've updated my question. What should I do if I need more information from the query?

Comment: The best thing about this solution, is that it can be easily updated to meet the new requirement: `select s.user, sum(s.score), sum(time)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nest query - the inner one to get the users' best answer for each problem and the outer one to sum them:

```
SELECT   user, SUM(score) AS total_score
FROM     (SELECT   user, problemid, MAX(score) AS score
          FROM     submission
          GROUP BY user, problemid) t
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: You need to use an alias like `MAX(score) as score` to access the value in the outer select.